# Real Time audio recording from two audio input and playing simultaneously in 2 audio output

Tags: audio, linux, raspbian-buster, alsa, arecord

I have one Raspberry Pi with 2 USB speakers and a mic system. I want to record simultaneously from one mic and play in another speaker. Like, MicA recording will be played in SpeakerB and MicB recording will be played in Speaker A simultaneously and in real-time. How is that possible? Please suggest some tutorials or some libraries.

Please suggest for any Linux System

Comment: I managed to record from one Mic and play in one speaker, but don't understand the configuration to record from 2 different mics and play in 2 different speakers at the same time.

Comment: I am using 2 USB speakers and 2 USB Mic systems